# split string in to 2 based on last occurrence of a separator

Tags: python, string

I would like to know if there is any built in function in python to break the string in to 2 parts, based on the last occurrence of a separator.

for eg:
consider the string "a b c,d,e,f" , after the split over separator ",", i want the output as

"a b c,d,e" and "f".

I know how to manipulate the string to get the desired output, but i want to know if there is any in built function in python.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use `rpartition(s)`. It does exactly that.

You can also use `rsplit(s, 1)`.

Comment: Not exactly: "a b c,d,e,f".rpartition(',') -> ('a b c,d,e', ',', 'f')

Comment: @Vanuan, It is EXACTLY that actually. Just also returns the separator for one reason or another:

str.rpartition(sep)
Split the string at the last occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing two empty strings, followed by the string itself.

Comment: `rsplit(s, 1)` and `rpartition(s)` output is different, you must admit.

Answer (score 74):

```
>>> "a b c,d,e,f".rsplit(',',1)
['a b c,d,e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 57):

You can split a string by the last occurrence of a separator with [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

> Returns a list of the words in the string, separated by the delimiter string (starting from right).

To split by the last comma:

```
>>> "a b c,d,e,f".rsplit(',', 1)
['a b c,d,e', 'f']
```

Comment: Wow three answers posted at the exact same time three minutes after question was asked. I used your answer like this `return full_path.rsplit(os.sep, 2)[0]`